# Deprecated jQuery callbacks- clarification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Since  jQuery 1.5](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  -  `jqXHR` objects returned by `$.ajax()`  implement the `Promise` interface.

The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) also state  that `jqXHR.done`  , `jqXHR.fail` , `jqXHR.always` are alternative constructs for the **deprecated** `success` / `fail`/ `complete` respectively.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are **deprecated** as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

ok.(known a long time ago)

But then I saw the `async` doc :

> **async  :** As of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async: false` with `jqXHR ($.Deferred)` is
>   deprecated; you must use the **success/error/complete** callback options
>   **instead** of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as
>   `jqXHR.done()` or the `deprecated jqXHR.success()`.

The wording here are very unclear (imho) - thus , I don't understand the meaning of it.

Question :

Are there any situations which **still** I need to use `success/error/complete` ? how come ? they are deprecated !

*nb  , why all this mess ? they change and remove methods and replace(! eg pipe , then) like every version*

Comment: Logical conclusion : `async: false` is deprecated.

Comment: @dystroyThe real question is `success` as still being used while being declared as `deprecated`....

Comment: @dystroy `async: false` is not deprecated, but `the use of async: false with jqXHR` is.

Comment: @xdazz this was just a joke... with a hint at the fact this horrible thing should have been removed long ago ^^

Comment: @dystroy Can't agree more :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Conclusion:

What is deprecated is **using async: false and jqXHR ($.Deferred) API at same time (The combining usage)**.

The `success/error/complete` callback options of `$.ajax()` are **not deprecated**.

The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are **deprecated**.

When using **async AJAX request** (`async: true`), you could use either `success/error/complete` callback options of `$.ajax()` **or** `jqXHR.done`, `jqXHR.fail` , `jqXHR.always`.

But when using **synchronous AJAX requests**(`async: false`),
you **should not** use the deferred API(`jqXHR.done`, `jqXHR.fail` , `jqXHR.always`), 
but use  `success/error/complete` callback options of `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Isn't `async: false` is deprecated?

Comment: @Satpal No, `the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred)` is.

Comment: @xdazz so `$.ajax(..async:false...).done(...)` is deprecated while `$.ajax(..async:false... , success:function(){...})` is not....right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, that's it :)